# React : I want to Call Two API in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, loopback

I am new to ReactJS , Actually Here I am working on pagination .I am fetching page data from server through API . I am using Loopback for API integration . Here I am showing 10 entries list on first page when user click on next it will show 10-20 entries and first page of entries will be skip. It possible with Loopback filter and I did it through manually but I am not able to implement it an app . I am showing first page data through this API Call `localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${userId}` It will show just 10 entries but I want that When user click on next it will skip previous 10 entries and include next 10 entries . API call for this `localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${userId}&&filter[skip]=${userId}`.
Could someone please help how to do this . thanks

**Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: how do you propose your API will know when to use the skip?

Answer (score 0):

there is setState in your getData function always you make data an empty array, in my opinion this firt reason you should remove it, and the second thing you have to make use spread to add the new response.data to your data in the state. I hope this is you are looking for.

```js
 getData(){
    const {userId}=this.state;
    this.setState({
      //delete the next line, don't make it empty array
      //data:[],
      loading:true
    })
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${userId}`)
    .then(response=>{
      console.log(response.data);
      //and here just you have to use spread like this
      let newData= this.state.data;
      if(newData.length>0){// to be sure data is not empty
      newData = [...newData, ...response.data];
      }else{
      newData = response.data;
      this.setState({
        data: newData,
        loading:false
      })
    })
  }
```